# Configure phpBB3 to use CloudFlare SSL

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare, phpbb3

How to configure the phpBB3 board to use the https connection available through CloudFlare - Flexible SSL Certificate (the free one).

Answer (score 0):

The [free SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl) option really just works automatically as far as issuance goes.

Notes: You still may have [mixed content issues](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-How-do-I-fix-the-SSL-Mixed-Content-Error-Message-) to address after the certificate has been issued.